# Unable to programmatically rename directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, rename

I have asp.net web forms project. It is created as "WebSite" and is running on my local iis.
In this project I've created folder with subfolder, where some picutes are stored.(~/listings/listing1, ~/listings/listing2...)

I can programmatically add new files to this subfolders, can delete this subfolders, but I can't rename them.
I've tried to rename this subfolders manually: when project is not runing - I am able to do so, when i run debuging in Visual Studio, I can't rename them even manually.

For programmatical renaming I am using this code:
    DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(oldListingFolderPath);
    rootDir.MoveTo(newListingFolderPath);
This cause error "Access to the path ... is denied."
I've granted full controll to this folder for NETWORK SERVICES, IIS_IUSERS, USER.
I've also tried to remove readonly attributes for files/folders in subfolder that should be renamed, but this didn't help.

Are there any other ways to rename needed subfolder. Or can you suggest any ways to find, what is blocking renaming of the folder.

EDIT1: paths of subfolders (~/listings/listing1) are mentioned just for example. When I am renaming directory, I am using full path to file: Server.MapPath("~/listings/listing1"). Sorry for not mentioning this before.

EDIT2: I've tried to do this in other way: firs I am creating new folder with needed new name, then I am copying existing folder to new folder and then I am deleting old folder. This works. But I still can't just rename existing folder...

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that when the ASP.NET web application executes, it still has a reference to(which means ASP.NET runtime is still using) the folder. Hence the access violation error.

Solution is to move the folder from `~` folder to elsewhere in the filesystem, not inside `~`.

Comment: Yes, probably ASP.NET is usint this dir somehow. I've replace "rename" action with "copy old folder to folder with new name" + "delete old folder" this is working, but looks like unneeded work and simple renaming will be more preferable.

Comment: Ah, some quirk eh? @IliyaKrinchiyan anyways, make an extension method for `DirectoryInfo` class and add your `ASPNETRenameFolder()` that does what you are trying to do. That way you can save a lot of time if it is being called at multiple places

Answer (score 1):

~/listings/listing1, ~/listings/listing2 - is a virtual path. 
To work with files you need to work with physical path.

Add PhysicalApplicationPath to directory path

```
string dir_path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "listings\listing1\";
```

or `Server.MapPath("/")` or `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` - depends on the type of application

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I am using physical path to files by doing Server.MapPath("~/listings/listing1"). Sorry that I didn't mention this before in my question

Comment: Plese, try this `Directory.Move(dir1, dir2);` . Maybe the problem is that the destination folder is already exists?

Comment: No, the destination dir doesn't exist. As I understand, Directory.Move(dir1, dir2) behaves same as dir1.MoveTo(dir2) method that I am using - the same error.

Comment: Maybe a file is locked. Sake of interest you can try this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4335478/2114398)